# rails: how to reset a users password with the click of a button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**requirement:** i want a button to reset the password of any user to "password" in the users#index page

**what i've tried**:
i didnt need a show action! so i replaced the name of show in the view as "reset password" and in the user_controller, i made the following changes

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id]) 
@user.password = "password"
@user.password_confirmation = "password"
if @user.save
    redirect_to users_url, notice: "Password was successfully reset!"
else
    redirect_to users_url, notice: "Password reset failed"
end
end
```

**result**: it doesnt work! no errors or anything. it reloads the page with "password reset failed" notice..

how to make it work? is it something to do with the http method called in the route?

Comment: can you print out @user.valid and see if it's actually valid?  Does "password" meet your password requirements?

Comment: as of now i have no validations in my user model.

Comment: did you print @user.valid? because generally if @user.save returns false it's a validation issue.  I've seen it fail and have strange validaion issues even when there were no validations defined

Answer (score 2):

If you have changed the view name from `show` to `reset password`, you also must change the action name and add this new route to your `routes.rb` file. But I think the best option in this case is the below:

Create the button in your `users#index`, calling the action `reset` in your controller:

```
<%= button_to "Reset Password", :controller=>"users", :action => "reset", :id=>user.id %>
```

Then, in the `users#controller`:

```
def reset
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.password = "password"
  @user.password_confirmation = "password"
  if @user.save
    redirect_to users_url, notice: "Password was successfully reset!"
  else
    redirect_to users_url, notice: "Password reset failed"
  end
end
```

Now, you just need to add this new action to your `routes.rb`:

```
post "users/reset"
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: nono! i only changed the display name to reset password! the action still points to show!

Comment: it shouldn't... delete the action `show` in your controller and restart the server... it should point to the `reset` action...

Comment: also make sure the `post "users/reset"` has been included in your `routes.rb` file..

Answer (score 0):

you might want to make a form in a view wich will be shown after authentication then make sure you make a hidden field wich sets the password_value to NULL after that on login create a form wich is shown when Password_value equals NULL to make the person choose his new password.

```
f.hidden_field :password_value, :value = nil
```

Have fun